# Lua: 'pairs' doesn't iterate over [1]

Tags: lua, iterator, lua-table

I quickly had to debug something, and wrote following function:

```
function dumpTable(t)
    for i,v in pairs(t) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            dumpTable(v)
        else
            print(i..":", v)
        end
    end
end
```

Now, for some reason

```
dumpTable({[1]="hello??", [2]="two", {[132]="something", [3.2]="else"}})
```

outputs

```
132:    something
3.2:    else
2:  two
```

notice how the first string is missing? But if I change its key..

```
dumpTable({["one"]="hello??", [2]="two", {[132]="something", [3.2]="else"}})
```

it outputs

```
132:    something
3.2:    else
one:    hello??
2:  two
```

This is so unintuitive I almost feel like making an idiot of myself not seeing the mistake..

(btw. I do know that my function will overflow the stack if the table contains a recursive reference, going to fix that later)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the inner table. You didn't give it a key, which mean that Lua will give it an array index. Namely, **`1`**. Which will overwrite the `[1]` key you used for `"hello??"`. So you need to give this table value a proper key, or you need to stop using integer keys for the others.

Or, to put it another way, the following two tables are identical:

```
{"first", "second", "third"}

{[3] = "third", [2] = "second", "first"} --Note the lack of a key for "first".
```